# Does every continuous map induce a homomorphism on fundamental groups?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $X$, $Y$ be topological spaces and $f:X \to Y$ be a continuous map. Does $f$ induce a homomorphism $f_* : \pi_1(X) \to \pi_1(Y)$? If not, what are the conditions on $f$ so that $f_*$ would be a homomorphism?

My motivation for knowing this is an application of disproving that $f$ is continuous by inducing a map $f_*$ and then showing that $f_*$ is not a homomorphism.

Comment: Yep. This is what is meant by the statement that the fundamental group is a functor.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I am learning category theory, but did not think of this simple explanation. This is a sufficient answer for me. Thanks!

Comment: Concerning your motivation: I'm puzzled how you intend to *induce* a map $f_\ast$ between homotopy classes of *continuous paths* in $X$ and $Y$ *without* knowing that $f$ is continuous. Can you elaborate on this application or give a reference, please?

Comment: @Martin I did not understand what exactly induced meant as I commented on user62163's answer. However, you can still assume that $f$ being non-continuous induces $f_*$ as a homomorphism and then derive contradiction.

Comment: Let $g:S^1 \to S^1, g(z)=z^2; f:S^1 \to S^1, f(z)=z^{0.5}$, then $g_* \circ f_* = 1_{S^1}$ which implies $1=g_*(f_*(1)) = 2f_*(1))$ which is not possible in $\pi_1(S^1)=\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Actually, the reason why the "square root function" does not induce a homomorphism is that it is not well-defined on $S^1$, so we cannot even talk of it as of a function, being continuous or discontinuous.

Comment: Yes, that's essentially what I tried to point out. It seems unlikely that it is possible for a discontinuous function to yield a well-defined map between the fundamental groups by pre-composition. I agree that in principle this idea would yield a valid way of disproving continuity, but I can't think of an example.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Suppose that $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is a continuous map and let $x_0 \in X$. Then the induced map $f_*: \pi_1(X,x_0) \rightarrow \pi_1(Y, f(x_0))$ is defined as follows. Let $[\alpha] \in \pi_1(X,x_0)$, i.e. $\alpha: I \rightarrow X$ is continuous and $\alpha(0) = x_0 = \alpha(1)$. We define

$f_*[\alpha] = [f \circ \alpha]$

Note that $f \circ \alpha:I \rightarrow Y$ is continuous and $(f \circ \alpha)(0) = f(x_0) = (f \circ \alpha)(1)$ so $f \circ \alpha$ is a loop in $Y$ at $f(x_0)$. Moreover, $f_*[\alpha]$ is well-defined: if $[\alpha] = [\beta]$ then there is an homotopy $H$ from $\alpha$ to $\beta$ and one readily verifies that $f \circ H$ is a homotopy from $f \circ \alpha$ to $f \circ \beta$.

We now show that $f_*$ is a homomorphism. The neutral element of $\pi_1(X,x_0)$ is $[c_{x_0}]$ where $c_{x_0}$ is the constant loop with value $x_0$. Then $f_*[c_{x_0}] = [f \circ c_{x_0}] = [c_{f(x_0)}]$ which is indeed the neutral element of $\pi_1(Y,f(x_0))$. We still need to show that $f_*$ preserves products, i.e. $f_*[\alpha] f_*[\beta] = f_*([\alpha][\beta])$ for any $[\alpha],[\beta] \in \pi_1(X,x_0)$.

Now, one the one hand $f_*[\alpha] f_*[\beta] = [f \circ \alpha][f \circ \beta] = [(f\circ\alpha)(f\circ\beta)]$ where

$(f\circ\alpha)(f\circ\beta)(s) = \begin{cases} (f \circ \alpha)(2s) &\mbox{if } 0 \leq s \leq \frac{1}{2} \\(f \circ \beta)(2s-1) &\mbox{if } \frac{1}{2} \leq s \leq 1  \end{cases}$

On the other hand, $f_*([\alpha][\beta]) = f_*[\alpha \beta] = [f \circ (\alpha \beta)]$ where

$(\alpha \beta)(s) = \begin{cases} \alpha(2s) &\mbox{if } 0 \leq s \leq \frac{1}{2} \\ \beta(2s-1) &\mbox{if } \frac{1}{2} \leq s \leq 1  \end{cases}$

so

$(f \circ (\alpha \beta))(s) = \begin{cases} (f \circ \alpha)(2s) &\mbox{if } 0 \leq s \leq \frac{1}{2} \\(f \circ \beta)(2s-1) &\mbox{if } \frac{1}{2} \leq s \leq 1  \end{cases}$

Therefore, $f_*[\alpha] f_*[\beta] = f_*([\alpha][\beta])$ for any $[\alpha],[\beta] \in \pi_1(X,x_0)$. So, $f_*$ is a homomorphism.

Comment: If $f$ induces a homomorphism then for every loop $\alpha$, $f \circ \alpha$ has to be a loop also. This was the crucial part I was missing. For there are some functions, e.g. square root on $S^1$ that send a loop to a path that is not a loop. This path may still be homotopic to the constant loop (consider sending a loop of degree one to a path ending at $(-1,0) \in S^1$ ), so we could still define a like-induced map.

Comment: No, if $\alpha: I \rightarrow X$ is a loop at $x_0$ then this just means $\alpha(0) = x_0 = \alpha(1)$. Therefore, if $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is a continuous map then we always have $(f \circ \alpha)(0) = f(x_0)$ and $(f \circ \alpha)(1) = f(x_0)$. Your example is not correct. The complex square root is only defined on the circle with one point deleted. Recall from complex analysis that to define the square root we need to make a branch cut.

Answer (score 2):

It is essential to be careful about base points here. Given a continuous map $f : X \to Y$, **and a base point $x_0 \in X$**, then $f$ induces a homomorphism $f_* : \pi_1(X,x_0) \to \pi_1(Y, f(x_0))$.  This is proved in any algebraic topology textbook and the other answer.

But there is something crucial here: $f_*$ **depends on the base point**. Here are two things to convince you of that.

---

First, you didn't mention that the spaces you consider are path-connected. If they are not, then the notion of "the fundamental group" of $X$ (or $Y$) does not even make sense. For every base point of $X$ (or $Y$), you can have a different fundamental group. If the spaces are path-connected, then they are all isomorphic and we can speak about "the fundamental group". But in general that is not the case.

For a silly example, consider $X = \mathbb{RP}^2$ and $Y = \mathbb{RP}^2 \sqcup S^1$, the disjoint union of a real projective plane and a circle. Consider $f : X \to Y$ to be simply the inclusion of one summand of the direct product.

The space $X$ is path-connected, so we can speak of "the fundamental group" of $X$, which is $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. However $Y$ is not path-connected, and depend on where you choose the base point you either get $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} = \pi_1(\mathbb{RP}^2)$ or $\mathbb{Z} = \pi_1(S^1)$.

Now if you choose any base point $x_0 \in X$, then you will always have $f(x_0) \in \mathbb{RP}^2$, and so $f$ will never induce a homomorphism from $\pi_1(\mathbb{RP}^2,x_0)$ to the fundamental group of $Y$ based at a point that is in $S^1$, i.e. $\mathbb{Z}$.

---

Second, even if your spaces are path-connected, then you need to specify which base point you choose to get a well-defined homomorphism. Indeed, I said earlier that for path connected spaces, fundamental groups with any base point will be isomorphic.

But this isomorphism depends on the choice of a path. Given $x_0, x_1 \in X$, any path $\gamma$ from $x_0$ to $x_1$ induces an isomorphism $\gamma_* : \pi_1(X,x_0) \to \pi_1(X,x_1)$. But if you change the path $\gamma$, you change the isomorphism! If you have another path $\gamma'$, then $\tau = \gamma' \circ \gamma^{-1}$ is a loop at $x_1$, i.e. an element of $\pi_1(X,x_1)$. The induced isomorphism $\gamma'_* : \pi_1(X,x_0) \to \pi_1(X,x_1)$ is nothing but $\gamma_*$ composed with conjugation by $\tau$, i.e. $\tau \circ (-) \circ \tau^{-1}$.

So even if your spaces are path connected, then a continuous map only induces a **conjugation class** of homomorphisms between fundamental groups, if you don't choose base points. If the fundamental groups are abelian then it does not matter (because conjugation is always trivial in an abelian group), but in general this matters.

---

If I may cite Grothendieck from [Ronald Brown's webpage](http://groupoids.org.uk/gpds.htm) (the emphasis is mine):

> What you write about Loday's n-Cat-groups makes sense for me and is quite interesting indeed. When you say they capture truncated homotopy types, I guess you mean "pointed 0-connected (truncated) homotopy types". This qualification seems to me an important one - while they are presumably quite adequate for dealing with a number of situations, it is kind of clear to me they are not for a "passe partout" description of homotopy types - **both the choice of a base point, and the 0-connectedness assumption, however innocuous they may seem at first sight, seem to me of a very essential nature**. To make an analogy, it would be just impossible to work at ease with algebraic varieties, say, if sticking from the outset (as had been customary for a long time) to varieties which are supposed to be connected. Fixing one point, in this respect (which wouldn't have occurred in the context of algebraic geometry) looks still worse, as far as limiting elbow-freedom goes! [...]

If you want to reread this answer with high-level language, then I'm saying "the fundamental group" is only a functor on **based** topological spaces, not general topological spaces. If you want a functor on all topological spaces, then you need to consider the [fundamental group**oid**](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/fundamental+groupoid) (see also [this MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/q/175923/36146)).